# Get 32px favicon.ico

Tags: android, httprequest, user-agent, favicon

Im trying to get the 32px favicon.ico of the websites, but the response it obtain is the 16px favicon, I guess because I´m trying to obtain it by the smarthphone, but I try to change the user agent of the http petition with no result here is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String baseUrl = getBaseUrl(url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUrl + "/favicon.ico");
            httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = (java.io.InputStream) httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Drawable favicon = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            final BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) favicon;
```

Any idea how to get it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.ico` file can contain several pictures. Therefore, the `favicon.ico` file you get may well contain a 16x16 picture *and* a 32x32 picture.

You can use the `icotool` command line tool to analyze a `.ico` file:

```
# On Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install icoutils
icotool -l favicon.ico
--icon --index=1 --width=16 --height=16 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0
--icon --index=2 --width=32 --height=32 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0
--icon --index=3 --width=48 --height=48 --bit-depth=32 --palette-size=0
# 3 pictures in this favicon.ico file
```

On Windows, when you open a `.ico` file with the default viewer (just double-click the file), the viewer let you navigate through the multiple pictures contained in the file. It does not print their resolution, but at least you have a clue about what is going on with your strange behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Smart phone can't effect that.Actually on some website favicon size 16px and other have 32px.
Like facebook,google,twitter have 16px favicon
And yahoo,google plus have 32 px favicon...