# Wrong display favicon.ico on android device

Tags: android, favicon

I have a problem with loading favicon.ico from some sites.
For example http://deti.fm/favicon.ico.
On decktop computer it loads good, but on android device it loads with defect pixels.
Here is screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wt73pwk2jnj86b/favicon.jpg

Here is code

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
is.close();
conn.disconnect();
os.close();
return bitmap;
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097092/get-32px-favicon-ico/22451780#22451780 . However, the sample favicon you mention is not is this case, as it contains only one picture. A 22x22 picture, which is quite small. That may be the reason why the rendering is not that good...